# PHP cURL - issues with accessing HTTPS site

Tags: php, curl

I have been using cURL code to access Beanstream for awhile now, and all of a sudden it stopped working as of yesterday.  I have determined that this has to do with accessing the HTTPS URL for Beanstream processing, as if I test that same code and just go to the HTTP URL, it works (of course it returns an insecure connection code).

Prior to the below code I was setting VERIFYPEER / VERIFYHOST to FALSE, which was working up until yesterday.

```
    $url = 'https://www.google.com'; 

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "/xxxx/public_html/_cert/GeoTrustGlobalCA_google.crt");

    $getResponse = (curl_exec($ch));
    curl_close($ch);

    print_r($getResponse);
```

I have setup the above test code to try and access Google via HTTPS.  I had read that a proper connection requires the VERIFYPEER / CAINFO options to be set, which I have done and grabbed the Google .crt and placed it on the web server as well.

I still get a 503 Service Unavailable error back though.

> The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
>
> Additionally, a 503 Service Unavailable error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Google's not a huge fan of cURL hitting their domain and will frequently block that sort of automated access. Have you tried other domains?

Comment: Yes I have also tried with a site of my own on HTTPS and I get the same 503 error back.

Comment: That sounds like you're hitting some sort of proxy server.

Comment: Not sure what you mean about proxy server ceejayoz.  The code had not changed at all and just stopped working, both for Beanstream AND Paypal.

Comment: If every HTTPS URL is returning a 503 with the same error message, it's highly likely that some sort of web proxy, firewall, etc. is getting in the way. Beanstream, PayPal, and Google are a) unlikely to all be down at the same time and b) unlikely to use the exact same error message.